# SVG and plugin for IE 32-bit && 64-bit

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, 32bit-64bit, processing.js

I'm on the lookout for a IE plugin that works with versions 6-8 of IE *and* for both 32-bit version and 64-bit versions.

So far I've looked at Adobe's SVG viewer but that has been discontinued for 2 years and I've looked at [SSrc](http://www.savarese.com/software/svgplugin/) but that only supports 32-bit versions of IE. Any one know of plugins that supports SVG preferrably in all version from 6-8 on both 32-bit and 64-bit on windows platform.

An alternative would be if any one could suggest a plugin that would allow to run processing.js in IE6-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solid, supported SVG plugins for IE, AFAICT, have gone the way of the dodo.  (You're [not the only one](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/wiki/SVG_Plugin_for_IE) clamoring for a solid SVG plugin for IE.  You may have already found the [Ssrc plugin](http://www.savarese.com/software/svgplugin/) and noticed it's 32-bit only.)

But you have quite a few options that *aren't SVG plugins*.

If you can get your users to do it, the easiest option would be to [prompt IE users](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started) to install [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) ([available for 32- and 64-bit OS's](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=161796)), a much more invasive plugin that supports SVG display along with all other Chrome rendering features.

If you can't count on Chrome Frame (you're not sure people will be comfortable installing it, or they won't have permissions, etc.), there are still ways to shim SVG output in IE6-8 (ordered from most recommended to least):

- Use [SVGweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/). Flash required, but most commonly used SVG specs are supported and performance will likely be excellent.
- Use excanvas.js. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856947/has-anyone-got-processing-js-working-in-ie). Might be a pain to configure and unforgiving, but excanvas is mature.
- Use [svg2vml](http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/).  I've never used it, and you'd need to connect it with processing somehow.

Another option would be to drop Processing and use Raphael, but I'm guessing Raphael's not powerful enough for your needs if you're using Processing.

HTH

Comment: Excellent answer. In reality I did end up with gRaphael. I need to do pie charts and bar graph (amongst other) rewritting to gRapheal was therefor pretty easy.

Comment: Glad it helped!  For simpler visualizations, Raphael really is a joy.

Comment: This is wrong that Google Chrome frame is supported on IE9 64 bit. Yes, it can be installed on 64-bit OSes, but for IE9 32 bit only.

Comment: @Denis The Menace Didn't know that. But why would you use Chrome frame for IE 9?  It already has SVG (and canvas) support.

Comment: Note that Chrome Frame is also going the way of the dodo: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html