# Processing script in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, processing.js

Why processing.js is not running in IE8? For example the demo given in processing document http://processingjs.org/learning/topic/rollover

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856947/has-anyone-got-processing-js-working-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and before do not support <canvas> - no Internet Explorer before version 9 will work with Processing.js because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly agree with Mike regarding the limitations of IE8 and lower, but apparently it is still possible, though it doesn't work right out of the box. See related question ["Has anyone got processing.js working in IE?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/856947/165031)