# How can I modify an image in IE7?

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a very specific problem with IE7 and I'd appreciate any insight anyone might have.

I need to be able to add text taken from the user and add it to an image so that image and text are a single image file easily saveable by the user. I've figured out how to do this using HTML5, but this needs to work in IE7 and IE8. Furthermore, this needs to work offline, client side, and without any third party browser plugins like Flash.

I realize this is a doozy. I've spent weeks on it myself, but the powers that be aren't taking "no" for an answer on this one. Please help!

Comment: Use the HTML5-Canvas to add firstly the image and secondly the text. Or send image and text to a server that combines them into one image.

Comment: i need to haul 50,000 tons of boulders, but my boss insists we use a VW bug...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), which [probably needs some tweaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856947/has-anyone-got-processing-js-working-in-ie) on IE7.

Or [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/helvetica.html) which uses vector graphics and allegedly works "out-of-the-box" for IE7.

Comment: Never heard of processing.js, I'll take a look at that. The issue I ran into with RaphaelJS is that I couldn't find a way to merge text and graphics in a saveable format. This whole thing needs to wind up as a PNG or JPEG, not a vector image. On top of that, I can report that RaphaelJS does _not_ work out-of-the-box on IE8.

Comment: @JonB Browsers that don't support the Canvas element have a *very* slim chance of being able to implement client-side image processing.

Comment: Actually, we found another way to do it that doesn't work in IE7 or IE8 by modifying a small project called [pngLib](http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/). Unfortunately, it relies on the [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which is not supported by IE7 and far too restricted by IE8 to support a roughly 800x600 image.